# python print eliminate more times printing to output

Tags: python, python-2.7

Code:

```
x = ['1', '2', '3']
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
rangeend = len(x)
for i in range(0, rangeend):
    with open("file20.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            count = 0
            line = line.strip()
            z = line.split(" ")
            if z[0] == x[i] :
                count = 1
                a = z[0], z[1]
                b = x[i],y[i]
                if a == b:
                    print "ok"
                    break
                else:
                    print "Failed"
                    break
            if count != 1:
                print "{} not found".format(x[i])
```

file20.txt:

```
1 a
2 b
5 c
```

`x` list has `3` but `file20.txt` does not have `3` at the begin of the line (first string)

What I am trying is I want to print is, `3 not found` in the file and print has to be done only once at the end.

Note: not only element `3`, any element if `x` list has but `file20.txt` file line does not have at the begin (first string). I want print does not found.

Below is the code output and `2` is actually present but it is printing `2 not found` (Actually it does not print `2 not found`) and `3` is not there in `file20.txt` but it is printing `3 not found` that is correct but the problem is it is printing 3 times. I just want it to print `3 not found`, only once.

```
0
('1', 'a') ('1', 'a')
ok
1
2 not found
('2', 'b') ('2', 'b')
ok
2
3 not found
3 not found
3 not found
```

Comment: So you want something like `"1, 2, 3 not found"` instead of printing each on separate lines?

Comment: Your count!=1 check needs to be moved outside the for loop if you don't want it repeated - from what I could understand, this is what you want. Right now it repeats it 'n' number of times where n is the number of lines in your file.

Comment: @sinewaver, If i move outside for loop only last number not found will print. say x = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] and ['a','b','c','d'] in this case i want print 3 and 4 both but it will print only 4

Comment: @ChuckM, I want to print separately and also i need to find 3 not found in file20.txt at the start of line

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `if count != 1` block outside the inner `for` loop looks like working. Have you tried that!

```
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
y = ['a','b','c','d']
rangeend = len(x)
for i in range(0, rangeend):
    with open("bob.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            count = 0
            line = line.strip()
            z = line.split(" ")
            if z[0] == x[i] :
                count = 1
                a = z[0], z[1]
                b = x[i], y[i]
                if a == b:
                    print "ok"
                    break
                else:
                    print "Failed"
                    break
        if count != 1:
            print "{} not found".format(x[i])
```

Comment: above code does not work as expected since 2 is present when we run it will tell 2 is not found and 3 is not found

Comment: My bad, as when I move the `count != 1` block outside it seems like working. I've edited my answer accordingly.